# How to seperate multiple select box values based on category and display as group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, multi-select

I have the following in my views

```
<%= collection_select(:thing, :free_things_ids, FreeThings.where(:shop_id => current_user.shop_id).all(:order =>'name ASC'), :id, :name, {:include_blank => '----Select----'}, {:multiple => true, :size => 10, :name=>'thing[free_things_ids][]'}) %>
```

and i want to change this. The above mentioned lists all the values in a multi-select box as shown below
[image]

and i want to change it as

[image]

And this is separated based on `category_id`. So how can i do this? Please help me.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `grouped_collection_select`, for example:

```
<%= collection_select(:thing, :free_things_ids, Categories.all, 
                      :free_things, :name, :id, :name, 
                      {:include_blank => '----Select----'}, 
                      {:multiple => true, :size => 10, 
                      :name=>'thing[free_things_ids][]'})
```

However this will fetch all `FreeThings`. If you want to query `where(:shop_id => current_user.shop_id)` you would have to do something more complex like:

```
collection = FreeThings.where(:shop_id => current_user.shop_id).order('name ASC')
               .group_by{|f| f.category.name} # Groups the free things collection by the associated category's name
               .map{|category_name, free_things| [category_name, free_things.map{|free_thing| [free_thing.name, free_thing.id]} } # Creates a set (array) of name and id of each free_thing for each group
# This would give a nested array like this:
# [
#   ["Cat 1", [
#     ["Thi 1", 1], ["Thi 2", 2], ["Thi 3", 2]
#   ],
#   ["Cat 2", [
#     ["Thi 5", 5], ["Thi 6", 6], ["Thi 7", 7]
#   ],
#   ...
# ]
selected = @thing.free_things.map(&:id) # This is the selected items, should be a array of ids


<%= select(:thing, :free_things_ids,  
           grouped_options_for_select(collection, selected),
           {:include_blank => '----Select----'}, 
           {:multiple => true, :size => 10, :name=>'thing[free_things_ids][]'})
```

You should properly put this in some helper. Feel free to ask about the collection query if there is something that is unclear, it's pretty complex.

Comment: After selecting the values it saves it in the join table but when click on edit to view the values, the values are not shown as selected.

Comment: Thats working great and  i have one more question. I have category id in this able and when grouping it groups by category id and i want to get the name form the category table. How can i do this? I have updated the current view.

Comment: It's the `group_by` method that handles the grouping, so you could just change that part to `group_by{|f| f.category.id}`. Hope i understood you correct, and that answers your question?

Comment: I have changed a bit and it works. Thankyou so much. I have accepted and upvoted the answer

Comment: No problem, glad i could help :)! And thanks for the reputation points!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grouped_collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select) helper from ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper.